# GIMP Selection Tool Select-To-Move 2.10

Tags: gimp

It seems like in 2.10 they reworked the selection tool in GIMP 2.10. I used to be able to use the rectangle selection tool, drag over an area and use the move tool to move that selection. When I try to do this in 2.10 however, I end up moving the whole image.

Upon searching it up, I only found 1 forum thread talking about how you need to 'commit' the selection by pressing Enter. When I do this it focuses on the selection and blacks out everything, shown in the link below. How do I get out of this odd mode and how do I use the selection tool to copy or move a selection in GIMP 2.10?

After I use rectangle select tool to select a part of the image and then press Enter to confirm my selection, I get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH7vs.png

The image shows yellow dotted line around the whole image and the selection is shown but nothing else is.

Comment: It's almost as if they go out of their way to make things confusing. Are they worried about being accused of plagiarizing Adobe Photoshop?

Comment: Yeah it's so confusing. I was already comfortable witih 2.8 and its intuitive design. When I tried to reinstall it, it crashes upon loading. Shame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the selected image section in combination with certain keys. I use GIMP 2.10.22 under Windows 10.

The selected image section is shown after a rectangle selection, for example, with the following mouse pointer:

[image]

The mouse pointer changes after pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in order to still move the selection:

[image]

The mouse pointer changes after pressing the combination <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to move the selection as a copy:

[image]

**Edit:**

I got it - you are not using the *Rectangle Select Tool* to select a rectangular region (keyboard: <kbd>R</kbd>) but using the Crop Tool to remove edge areas from image or layer (keyboard: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). This of course is different.

Please note **Delete cropped pixels** is enabled here and this is resulting in the second window.

[image]

For further information I recommend watching some YouTube Video like [Using Crop and Move Tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HAoov9a6b_w). Crop and selection were clearly explained in this tutorial for different use cases.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to respond. It's clear that my question may have not protrayed my issue. I've updated it and hope it'll make things more clear. In GIMP 2.8, I was able to drag the rectangle select tool over a selection and copy it with ctrl-c, for example. Then I could paste with ctrl-v that selection and move it. When I do the same in 2.10, it does not work (as an example). I hope this example helps with understanding the essence of my question.

Comment: After selection, when I use ctrl-c it copies the whole entire layer. When I select and press Enter, it does what the image in the link in the post looks like. I'm new to GIMP so I don't know what other info I can give.

Comment: @useruser - see my edit and the YouTube video link!

Answer (score 0):

The real answer, I finally found out, is that I was accidently using the Crop feature instead of the Rectangle Select feature. When pressing Enter, it commits the crop the image to selection by default. I would then CTRL-C and undo and paste. This is for anyone else who may have had a similar issue: hover over to see if you are using the correct tool.

Comment: As I mentioned in my Edit two days ago